# Is the phrase, "just like any other day," non-restrictive?

Tags: commas

Would the sentence, "*A car drove by, just like any other day*," would a comma go before "*just*"? If so, why? Is it non-restrictive? Is there a good way to know if something is non-restrictive rather than restrictive?

Comment: This is not a relative construction, so I'm not sure what you mean by 'non-restrictive'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-restrictive clause will not change the meaning of a sentence if it is omitted, and should be preceded by a comma. In your example, "just like any other day" is non-restrictive since it is not providing any essential information, so the comma is necessary.

[The Center for Writing Studies: Grammar Handbook: Restrictive and Non-restrictive Clauses](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above posts- It's an adverb clause. But, to answer your question, I wouldn't put a comma there. We put commas if the sentence begins with an adverb clause but not if it's at the end. Check out this example:

While I was drinking beer (adverb clause- telling is when something happens modifying the verb answer), I answered the phone (main clause). We use a comma here.

I answered the phone while I was drinking beer. (no comma- the adverb clause comes at the end).

Hope that helps! 
-Tom

Comment: Hi Thomas. Keep in mind that "above" and "below" can change depending upon the view the reader chooses (and new answers may appear "above" yours that don't mention adverb clauses at all!). It might be better to refer to the answer by the user name (or even use the "share" link to add a link to it in your answer).

Answer (score -1):

*Just like any other day* is not a clause. It is an [adverbial](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/adverbialterm.htm) (in this case, an adverbial phrase) that provides more information about the independent clause. The terms restrictive and non-restrictive don't apply to it; they apply to [relative clauses](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/restrictive-and-nonrestrictive-clauses).